# Google Chrome Developer Tools not displaying

Tags: google-chrome

A while ago, I did something unknowingly (I happenned to some key with Ctrl pressed). First, it did like it was zooming in. Then I tried to zoom out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `-` and the next time (now) I opened it it displays just a plain white. I didn't get any options to reset to default settings. I'm using Chrome V19.

[image]

Comment: Would be best if you could take the time to write your question. This is easiest by "editing" the other question, copying the text, and pasting this edited question.

Comment: There were already some discussions made. I thought that would help.

Comment: You can flag a question to be moved.  See this for some insight into the process:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site .

Comment: Have you tried using a new profile?

Comment: adding new profile would help but i cannot use the my existing data (bookmarks, history and all)..

Comment: You have to import the bookmarks and other things in your new profile to use them.

Comment: how would I?

If I copy my previous profile's from file C:\Users\RAJ BD\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data, the problem still remains.

Comment: If you wish, you can transfer information from your old user profile to your new one. However, this action is not recommended, since a part of your old profile was corrupt. With that in mind, to transfer your old bookmarks, copy the "Bookmarks.bak" file from the "Backup default" folder to your new "Default" folder. Once moved, rename the file from "Bookmarks.bak" to "Bookmarks" to complete the migration. [Source](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059)

Comment: I couldn't locate the Default folder..

Comment: Just press the **Windows+R** key and paste this address `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ ` and you will see the `Default` folder.

Comment: Also ping the user just @username and it will notify the specific usr.

Comment: thanks for that.. and i did the same %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\ but no Default folder...

Comment: Then may be your chrome installation has any problem. Try to uninstall it with `Revo uninstaller` and install it again. Here is my chrome folders http://i.imgur.com/SSYxz.jpg

Comment: @avirk Default is the only missing folder in mine..

Comment: Then try to uninstall the chrome as I suggested and reinstall may fix the problem. [Link for Revo](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same thing happened to me but I finaly found the files that contain the settings for the inspector.
Just go to *\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage* and delete these two files :

```
chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal
```

And you're done.

Comment: thanks.. I had been searching the file but couldn't find.. then I replaced the Profile with one I had backd up ealier... :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my Chrome Theme is not compatible with Developer Tools I guess. I change to another theme then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, may be developer tools out of the screen. 
İf you using windows

```
Taskbar->Developer Tools icon click-> Application review-> windows+right button
```

or

```
Taskbar->Developer Tools icon click-> Application review right click->Move-> move to screen with arrow buttons
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

1. Uninstall chrome
2. Go to AppData\Local\Google
3. Delete Chrome folder

Note: Deleting these files alone did not work for me

- chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage
- chrome-devtools_devtools_0.localstorage-journal