# How to re-enable Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm on Windows 7 running Google Chrome 41 and somehow my developer tools are disabled. `Inspect Element`  in the context menu is grayed out, all the Developer options under the hamburger and More Tools are also grayed, and there doesn't seem to be anyway around it.

I've found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692006/how-to-uninstall-remove-developer-tools-from-google-chrome) but I couldn't find `"disabled": true` in my Preferences file. I've checked and Chrome isn't starting with the `--disable-dev-tools` flag either. I've wandered through the registry looking for an entry that might be causing this but so far I've found no way to re-enable devtools. I am a developer, I need them.

How can I re-enable Chrome's Developer Tools?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/439353/google-chrome-developer-tools-not-displaying?rq=1) might help

Comment: @Ramhound The files mentioned in the answer don't exist for me.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome and now I have the dev tools. I'm still curious what might have caused it to be disabled to begin with, but I guess I'll never know for sure now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a key called `DeveloperToolsDisabled` in the Registry, See both

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
Computer\HKEY_USERS\[USER GUID]\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
```

If it's set to `1`, change to `0` and restart Google Chrome.